# Trace outofmemory error

Tags: android, trace, out-of-memory

I am getting the following stack trace error on google play. It's only happening with my most recent update, which included adding some third-party code that requires an internet connection as well as updates to my code. I cannot figure out how to recreate this problem nor can I seem to figure out where it is coming from. Any ideas?

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=8519KB, Allocated=5304KB,
>   Bitmap Size=24283KB) at
>   android.webkit.ByteArrayBuilder$Chunk.(ByteArrayBuilder.java:136)
>   at
>   android.webkit.ByteArrayBuilder.obtainChunk(ByteArrayBuilder.java:127)
>   at android.webkit.ByteArrayBuilder.append(ByteArrayBuilder.java:55) at
>   android.webkit.LoadListener.data(LoadListener.java:744) at
>   android.net.http.Request.readResponse(Request.java:377) at
>   android.net.http.Connection.processRequests(Connection.java:386) at
>   android.net.http.ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionThread.java:144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, someone is loading a 24 MB bitmap (Bitmap Size=24283KB).  I suspect this is your problem.

If it is you that is creating the bitmaps, I would recommend reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966) and this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Comment: Loading as in downloading correct? All of my images are included in the resources and I don't download any content from the internet. So I guess it's safe to say I need to look into the code of this third-party and see what it is they're fetching.

Comment: Correct, it looks like they're doing some kind of http activity that is slurping down a bitmap.